# How to update records when subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

Example, I need to auto/random assign a "new" Leader to lead the students (select only 1 student from each types) and by daily basis, assume there are total 10 leaders in the Leader table.

But i am getting wrong result by using the query below, it will update all students to same leader id in the first time.

```
UPDATE students 
   SET student_status = 'assigned'
     , leader_id = 'abc' 
 WHERE student_id IN 
         ( SELECT student_id 
             FROM  
                ( SELECT * 
                    FROM students
                ) s 
            WHERE student_status = 'New'  
            GROUP
               BY type_id)
```

My expected result similar to the below query, but i don't want to run another logic to generate the randomized student_id:

```
UPDATE students
SET student_status='assigned', leader_id='abc' 
WHERE student_id IN ('T0123','S0222','T7777','S8888')


student_id | type_id | leader_id | student_status
-----------+---------+-----------+---------------
T0121      | Type 1  |    xyz    | assigned
T0122      | Type 1  |           | new
T0123      | Type 1  |           | new
S0221      | Type 2  |           | new
S0222      | Type 2  |           | new
S0223      | Type 2  |    xyz    | assigned
T7777      | Type 3  |           | new
T7779      | Type 3  |    xyz    | assigned
S8888      | Type 4  |    xyz    | assigned
S8887      | Type 4  |           | new
S8886      | Type 4  |           | new
```

Comment: you mean each `student_id` will get different `leader_id`? OR according to type_id you will assign `leader_id`

Comment: I don't get why this `SELECT student_id FROM  (SELECT * FROM students)  AS s WHERE student_status ='New'  GROUP BY type_id` cannot be just `SELECT student_id FROM  students WHERE student_status ='New'  GROUP BY type_id`

Comment: @GordonLinoff haha sorry, i never think i got the prompt reply from you guys, appreciated. I had included the sample data, but i found out the data was wrongly aligned, so removed it and now with the update version. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: @M.Hemant ya student_id will get different leader_id.  Every time the query has to only select  1 student from each type.

Comment: ok, then you need to write `cursor` then you can assign leader_id based on type_id

Answer (score 0):

Use RAND() to get a random leader_id between 1 and the max leader_id and a subquery using ROW_NUMBER and OVER to get a random student_id per type to update

```
UPDATE students s
JOIN (SELECT type_id, student_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type_id ORDER BY RAND()) rnum
      FROM students 
      WHERE status = 'new') r ON r.type_id = s.type_id AND
                                 r.student_id = s.student_id AND 
                                 rnum = 1
SET leader_id = (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * MAX(leader_id)) FROM leaders),
    status = 'assigned'
WHERE status = 'new'
```

Comment: It is the most important part too: select only 1 student from each types each time running the query.

Answer (score -1):

For MySQL :

```
UPDATE students 
SET student_status='assigned', leader_id='abc' 
WHERE student_id IN (
    SELECT student_id FROM  (
         SELECT * FROM students)  AS s 
    WHERE student_status ='New'  GROUP BY type_id ORDER BY RAND()
    )
```

Comment: Above query will assign leader id to random students of different types

Comment: let me know if u have any issue

Comment: Why are you writing comments to your own answer? Add the explanation to the answer instead.

Comment: Thanks Raj. But i think the result will be the same, it will update all "new" students. and i try to avoid using RAND(), because it used up a lot of server resources (based on my experiences) and my data will grow to millions rows.

Answer (score -1):

This should work. This will Pick 1 new student each time from every Type and will update Status and Leader ID accordingly.

```
UPDATE students 
SET student_status = 'assigned'
, leader_id = 'abc' 
WHERE student_id IN (
    SELECT student_id FROM (
        SELECT c.student_id, c.student_status, c.type_id
        FROM students C 
        WHERE c.student_status = 'New'
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) AS shuffled_items
    GROUP BY type_id
)
```

Comment: but each time only select 1 student from each types

Comment: @jack can you check the new script added is fulfill your requirement or not?

Comment: I think the result is still the same, your query will select all the new students as well.

Comment: @Jack. I think your requirement is clear now. Please check the updated script. This will pick One student each time from each type and update values for them only accordingly.

Comment: @Jack, sorry as i thought first the solution required for MSSQL. The edited solution will now work for MySQL. You can have a check.

Comment: Actually i have tried the similar query like yours, but i dunno why, it just update all new students instead of the 4 students?!! i suspect it is  mySQL bug when handling  with subquery. i will try yours in a short while. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194899/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-jack).